# plot a bar chart from a selected column in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe, histogram, bar-chart

If I have a variable `hotel_type` from my `DataFrame` and I count for the number of each different `hotel_type`

The following command:

```
`df.hotel_type.value_counts()`
```

gives the result:

```
Apartment            3157
Hotel                 115
Villa                  54
Bed and Breakfast      48
Holiday home           21
```

Question: How can I plot a bar chart and histogram with x-axis : hotel type and y-axis : the number of each hotel type by using `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [Series.plot.barh](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.barh.html):

```
df.hotel_type.value_counts().plot.barh()
```

Update:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = df.hotel_type.value_counts()

x = list(a.index)
y = list(a)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
width = 0.75 # the width of the bars 
ind = np.arange(len(y))  # the x locations for the groups
ax.barh(ind, y, width, color="blue")
ax.set_yticks(ind+width/2)
ax.set_yticklabels(x, minor=False)
for i, v in enumerate(y):
    ax.text(v + .25, i + .25, str(v), color='blue', fontweight='bold') #add value labels into bar
plt.title('title')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can I add the values in the bar chart?

Comment: and how to do with `matplotlib`?

Comment: I saw it. Thank you!

Comment: hi. I saw your code and it was very helpful! but I need the data to be in vertical ( bars in x-axis and numbers in y-xis. Any suggestions? thanx